# Is this jQuery line of a tutorial necessary?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with the German book (mediated title) "jQuery the practice book".

In one of the first tutorials the given JS code is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#box p").click
    (
        function()
        {
            $("#box p").removeClass("green");
            $(this)
            .addClass("green")
            .parent()
            .removeClass()
            .addClass("boxColor-" + $("#box p").index(this));
        }
    );
});
```

the CSS is like this:

```
<style type ="text/css">
    p {
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    .green{
        color:#009933;
        background-color:#E2FFEC;
        cursor:default;
    }
</style>
```

and the HTML is this:

```
<body>
<div id="box">
    <p>Erster Absatz</p>
    <p>Zweiter Absatz</p>
    <p>Dritter Absatz</p>
</div>
</body>
```

What makes me stuck is this line of the jQuery script:

```
.addClass("boxColor-" + $("#box p").index(this));
```

The Tutorial of the book explains this with a reason like "On which way else we could get the p box related Class?"

But I don't get the point what is happening in that line?

And even if I remove this line, the result I'm seeing keeps being the same.

so, what does happen here? and is it really necessary in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That line is adding a `boxColor-N` class to the `#box` element, where N is the index of the `<p>` you just clicked.

Since there is nothing in the CSS that targets such a class and also no script code that works with it, there are no observable effects.

Comment: Yep I checked that with the opera inspector. Seems to be a bad tutorial book for me... this isn't the first tiem of such explanation... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This line adds a class name. The value that is added is a concatenation of the string `boxColor-` and the index of the relevant paragraph element.

The index of the element is extracted by using the [jQuery `index()` function](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Regarding your question if it is needed at all really depends on what that class name does. All it's really doing here is adding a class name. If that class name has any other uses such as changing CSS properties then yes, it is needed. In your example, there is no CSS rule for that value - so nothing really changes or happens.

To see this actual *doing* something, you can add a CSS rule like this:

```
boxColor-0 {
        background:red;
}
boxColor-1 {
        background:green;
}
boxColor-2 {
        background:blue;
}
```

With these rules, when you click on a `<p>` element, it's background color will change.

Comment: Just tryed. But it would have to be '.boxColor-0 {...}.boxColor-1 {...}.boxColor-2 {...}', wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it was an error but as the other explained this will add a class something like "boxColor-" + the index of the element.

But the code

```
$("#box p").removeClass("green");
            $(this)
            .addClass("green")
            .parent()
            .removeClass();
```

has a closing `;` on `.removeClass();`

In jQuery the Chaining is used to call multiple functions on an element selected but because you are ending the chaining with this line.  Otherwise you will add the class to the parent of the `<p>` tag

```
.removeClass();
```

You're not applying the addClass to any object try removing the ;  and then  use something like

```
 $("#box p").removeClass("green");
        $(this)
        .addClass("green")
        .parent()
        .removeClass()
        .addClass("boxColor-" + $("#box p").index(this));
```

Here is an example of how it should work.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/7dDCM/1/)

Comment: the `;` is a copy apste error as the .addClass() lane begins currently with `//` in my Code. --> Thanks + Fixed.